# data-toggle='button' only after condition check in angular component

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4

Need to check some condition when click and if it return true then toggle where is has been clicked

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active" (click)='example()'>
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary"  (click)='example()'>
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary"  (click)='example()'>
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can pass `$event` to `example()` which would give you access to event properties such as `target` and `target.name`/`target.id`. At minimum try the following. Change the handler in the template to pass `$event` `(click)='example($event)'`. Then update the handler to take the `$event` argument and use it as necessary `example($event) { console.log($event.target); }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method like this:

```
status:boolean;
someMethod(value: string): void {
this.status = value;

if (your condition) {
  //Your operation here
} else {
 //your other work.
}
```

}

Here the status will help you store the value and apply your condition.